# Generate datetime using CRON Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a cron expression stored in a table like

[image: *]

I need to generate timestamp starting from CurrentTimestamp to 2 Years.Sample output below.

[image]

I am not sure if it is possible using SQL or PLSQL.Can you please guide me?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in to do that. You'll likely have to build your own interpreter if you can't find a 3rd party or open-source package to do it.

Comment: Have a look at [DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#i1009923) The [calendaring syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#BABFBCEF) is quite sophisticated.

Comment: And I thought  storing timestamps as a string was a bad idea. This seems like the most obscure way to avoid using proper data type I have seen. Use a proper modern scheduler or store timestamps as timestamp.